# React state updates text input field, but unable to update another <p> element

Tags: reactjs

See the code below, I'm basically just trying to make a simple page that takes the <input> from typing (will be restricted to numbers, hence 'Numbers'), and then simply outputs a <p> with whatever was typed.
For some reason, when I do this, it shows the initial state, 0, and then upon the next input into the text field it changes to nothing. However, the text field is updating correctly, as expected.
Any help is appreciated, as I can't seem to find any examples of this, except the same Clock example everywhere.

```
export default class Numbers extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {numbers: '0'};
}
updateNumbers(event) {
    this.setState({
        numbers: event.target.numbers
    });
}
render () {
        return (
          <div>
            <input type='text' name='numbers' value={this.state.numbers} onChange={event => this.updateNumbers(event)} />
            <p>{this.state.numbers}</p>
          </div>
             );
        };
```

}

Comment: `numbers: event.target.numbers` should be `numbers: event.target.value`

Comment: Huh. Thanks, that's solved it. If you get the time, I'd appreciate why this is the case.

Comment: because the `event` object contains a `target` property, which is an input, which has a `value` attribute, containing whatever is in the text box, but does not have a `numbers` field, so `event.target.numbers` is `undefined`.  So when you set your `state.number` to `undefined`, it makes the input value blank.  If you set it to the contents of the `input` (`event.target.value`), then it sets the state to those contents, so the input keeps the correct value.

Comment: That's fantastic, thanks, makes sense now. Most appreciated.